# What is the best optimization technique used for dimensional reduction in features selection?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

There are many optimization techniques used for this purpose but what are the best  or how can i chose the suitable technique for my work..Thanks

Comment: There is no single answer to that question (and certainly not with the zero information you are providing). The best way is to select meaningful features upfront, i.e. those that are truly discriminative. Use you brains, not artificial neurons.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .. really i forgot giving more details .. my dataset are retinal images .

Comment: Do you really think that you added anything informative in this comment ??

Comment: What exactly should  i add? .. if you intend specific points illustrate please

Comment: My last attempt: what is the best vehicle ?

Answer (score 1):

PCA is the most widely used in the industry.
Choosing the right techniques mainly depends on the kind of data you have.
If you have only numerical it can be a good choice, but for non numerical values there are better techniques such as Random Forrest / Ensemble Trees.

If you have high computing resources you can combine Missing Values Ratio and Backward Feature Elimination.